# Python: Wrong function argument?

Tags: python

What is wrong with this code? 
I get this error :

> Oops, try again. trip_cost should take exactly 3 arguments!

What is wrong with this code?

```
def hotel_cost(nights):
    return 140*nights
def plane_ride_cost(city):
    if city == "Charlotte":
        return 183
    elif city == "Tampa":
        return 220
    elif city == "Pittsburgh":
        return 222
    elif city == "Los Angeles":
        return 475
def rental_car_cost(days):
    money = 40 * days
    if days >= 7:
        money -= 50
    elif days >= 3:
        money -= 20
    return money

def trip_cost(days,city,spending_money):
    return rental_car_cost(days)+hotel_cost(days) + plane_ride_cost(city) +spending_money
```

Comment: Where are you calling `trip_cost`?

Comment: where do you call `trip_cost`?

Comment: Please post complete code. You are not calling trip cost in the code given

Comment: I'm guessing this is an assignment, and your teacher has some "driver script" that loads your code and calls `trip_cost`, and this error means that you didn't follow the instructions correctly.

Comment: @abarnert, If I remember correctly, this is a Codecademy question

Comment: this is course from code academy, and the editor calling trip cost without my interference.

Comment: @sshashank124 Exactly !

Comment: Then either (a) you didn't follow the instructions, or (b) CodeAcademy is just handling all `TypeError` exceptions with this message (because it's the most likely reason for a `TypeError` on this assignment) and you have a `TypeError` somewhere else. Can you link to the instructions? (I don't know much about how CodeAcademy works…)

Comment: 1.Modify your trip_cost function definition. Add a third argument, spending_money.
2.Modify what the trip_cost function does. Add the variable spending_money to the sum that it returns.   

This is what I have to do.

Comment: My best guess is that it's a combination of both: Maybe you're taking the arguments in the wrong order, so you get, say, the city name and the days mixed up. So, inside `rental_car_cost(days)`, where you try to do `if days >= 7`, it's comparing the string `"Charlotte"` to the number `7`, which raises a `TypeError`, which CodeAcademy assumes is because you put the wrong number of parameters rather than the wrong order, so it gives you a misleading error message.

Comment: Wait a second, you've tagged this `oop`. Are these functions supposed to methods of a class, rather than plain functions? In that case, it's a different problem: you're just missing the `self` parameter… (If they're not methods, then this isn't an OOP problem.)

Comment: Oh, sorry THIS IS NOT an OOP problem, I'm new at stackoverflow and I'm still learning. I apologize for misleading

Comment: No problem; just edit the question to remove the tag. And while you're editing: if you can add a link to the CodeAcademy page, please do so; if you can't, please put more information into the question (whatever seems relevant from that page, and/or how to find it—question number or whatever they use).

Comment: See [this screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wcTHb.png), I ran your code in my Codecademy account and it works perfectly!

Comment: http://www.codecademy.com/courses/python-beginner-P5YtY/1/5?curriculum_id=4f89dab3d788890003000096

Can you see the content of this page?

Answer (score 2):

The error given is slightly misleading to you, because you have got your arguments passed in the wrong order.

The instructions ask for

> define a function called trip_cost that takes two arguments, city and days.

Which you later will add a third argument called `spending_money`

> Modify your trip_cost function definition. Add a third argument, spending_money.

The resulting function you want is:

```
def trip_cost(city,days,spending_money):
    return rental_car_cost(days) + hotel_cost(days) + plane_ride_cost(city) + spending_money
```

If you changed the argument orders you would get an error like so:

> Oops, try again. trip_cost('Tampa', 7, 0) raised an error: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

This is in Step 6.

**So changing your order should do it.**

For step 7, I tried changing the order and I got this error as well:

> Oops, try again. trip_cost should take exactly three parameters: city, days, and spending_money (in that order).

Source: Just tried it myself since I took the course before.

**EDIT**: Just so people are clear about this, it is **perfectly okay** if your parameter order isn't in that specific order when you write your own programs. However, in assignments and projects where a script not written by you is used to check if your function does what it should do, **you should follow instructions** on the order of it. I've had students come to my office hours demanding their function is right (and it is) but the grading script docked points off because of different parameter orders. Then we TAs have to manually regrade it. In short, it's fine if the order isn't exactly the same as someone else's only when you're not being graded with a script or the **requirements** do not force you to follow the order.

[image: error]

Comment: Ha, exactly what I suggested in my comments; CodeAcademy screwed up and confused their users by not considering that they might have gotten `days` and `city` backward (even though they _did_ consider the exact same thing in the very next question).

Comment: @abarnert ikr. I should probably add that it's not an issue in real life. when others come by to view it. Can't blame codecademy through, checking for correctness isn't easy

Comment: From your edit: In real life programming, you're often coding to a defined API. Not necessarily a formal spec, just you and the guy in the next cubicle or the rest of the people on the email list agreed that they're going to call your function with `days, city, spending_money`, and if you change your mind about the order without telling them it'll be just as big a problem for the real-life project as it is at CodeAcademy. The only hope is if you always make sure to write better unit tests than theirs. :)

Comment: @abarnert agree with you on that. at least CodeCademy gives a prompt on the specific order now (it did in my screenshot), so that's good. Sides, parameter orders are usually a defined requirement, not a formal spec but something discussed as you said.

Comment: Of course I won't admit that I ever agreed to a parameter order with the guy in the cubicle next to me and then changed my mind after he'd written all the unit tests, it's just something that could happen in theory. And it might cost you an expensive bottle of bourbon to make up for it. In theory.